# Ember Data store.unloadAll('myType') not unloading records

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, store

I need to unload certain types from the ember data store. I am doing this in a didTransition route hook. What is odd is that some of the types I try to unload are actually unloaded, but not all types are. All records for some types remain in the store after the call to store.unloadAll. Even weirder is that I can unload the remaining types manually by running unloadAll again in the console.

What is causing unloadAll to work at one point, but not another? Relationships?

Note: None of the objects are dirty.

```
var typesToUnload = ['typeOne', 'typeTwo', 'typeThree'];
typesToUnload.forEach(function(type) {
    store.unloadAll(type);
});
```

Comment: it might be scheduling it to run later and they are scheduling over each other.  Is it consistently failing to unload the first or last or only unloading the first or last in the array of types?

Comment: @Kingpin2k it consistently doesn't unload types that are related to other types. I have found that if I unload them in a certain order it works. However that feels fragile based on the number of types we have, so we are going to just reload the page or do a App.reset() instead. Thanks for commenting.